# Conditional comments only work when file extension is html

Tags: xhtml, conditional-comments

The issue I am encountering is exactly what the title of this question says, conditional comments on my page only work if the extension is html.

If this is saved as an xhtml file, the conditional comments don't work and the page displays "Not internet explorer" regardless of browser. However, when the file is renamed to html, everything functions normally. This wouldn't be an issue, except the page is required to be an xhtml file.

Here's a minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
        <!--[if IE]>Internet explorer<![endif]-->
        <!--[if !IE]>-->Not internet explorer<!--<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

The only thing that I could find through testing and searching for a few hours on Google and this site is the second line which unfortunately didn't do anything.

Comment: I've never seen an `.xhtml` extension before.  Are you sure you aren't confusing `xHTML` as a spec for modern HTML versus a file extension?  Generally when you use strict/transitional `xHTML` in your code, you still use `.html` extension.

Comment: "Change the file name from home.html to window.xhtml." https://support.fastspring.com/entries/20070328-look-and-feel-creating-custom-store-styles  The file is rejected if it's not `.xhtml`

Answer (score 2):

You're testing in IE9 right?

This is something that only happens when you test the file locally. If you tested the page via a web server you would find that conditional comments work fine regardless of the file extension.

The reason is that accessing a file locally with a .xhtml extension in IE9 (or other makes of browser, but not IE8 or earlier) is equivalent to serving the page with a `application/xhtml+xml` content type.

That is, IE9 is processing the file as "true" XHTML. Normally, XHTML files are served with a `text/html` content type, and therefore are processed as HTML not XHTML.

True XHTML requires that the markup is parsed using and XML parser. The XML parsing rules are very strict, and do not allow for nasty hacks like conditional comments,  so IE9 in `application/xhtml+xml` mode does not, and indeed cannot, support them.

Comment: I am unable to find that conditional comments work fine: http://wademcgillis.com/example.xhtml

Comment: Interesting. You've got Apache set up to serve .xhtml files as content type `application/xhtml+xml` so the same issues with XML handling apply. Note that this means that IE8 and earlier cannot handle the .xhtml files at all.

Comment: +1 for the correct explanation. -½ for stating that “Normally, XHTML files are served with a text/html content type”. While true that this is how it is commonly done, serving application/xhtml+xml for XHTML files is still The Right Thing To Do™ and should not be discouraged. Browsers get faster when they can rely on their XML parsers instead of the slow tag soup parsers.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert - As someone who does serve my web pages as `application/xhtml+xml` to any user agent that says it will accept it, I agree, and didn't think I was encouraging using `text/html`, merely, as you did, acknowledging reality. However, the browser manufacturers dispute that parsing HTML is slower than parsing XML. In particular, they argue that much more effort goes into optimizing their HTML parsers because it is by far the more commonly used one.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code after including jquery library and in this way your xhtml will work in the same way than html page.

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = "<!--[if IE 8]><i></i><![endif]-->";
        var isIE8 = (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length == 1);

        div.innerHTML = "<!--[if IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
        var isIE9 = (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length == 1);

        if (isIE8) {
           $('html').addClass('ie').addClass('ie8');
        } else
        if (isIE9) {
           $('html').addClass('ie').addClass('ie9');
        }
     //]]>
    </script>
```